# Sbt 0.13 ScriptEngine is Null for getEngineByName(“scala”)

Tags: scala, sbt, scriptengine, dynamic-compilation

I have problem in using ScriptEngine from sbt 0.13.8

**build.sbt**

```
fork in run := true

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.11.6"
)
```

**UseConfig.scala**

```
object UseConfig {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = {
        import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager

        val e = new ScriptEngineManager(null).getEngineByName("scala")

        println(e)
    }
}
```

and it prints null.

When I run a similar code in scala 2.11.6 console a scala engine is found successfully.

p.s. Is there are any other ways to compile dynamically scala code under sbt?